# How to browse a remote Git repo on VSTS using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

How do I browse a remote Git repository in VSTS usinbg Visual Studio? If I use Source Control Explorer, I get the screen below. If I switch from Git plugin to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server plugin, it tells me the active solution is controlled by a different source control plugin. I know I should stay with the Git plugin because my solution is controlled by Git yet I don't understand why the link is telling me to switch the plugin and the rest of screen is disabled. Is the Source Control Explorer not compatible with Git? Is there another way to browse? If I connect to the repor using Team Explorer, I can either clone or connect. If I connect, it takes me to Team Explorer Home pane.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Source control explorer is for TFVC repositories. There's nothing to "explore" in a Git repo -- the stuff on your file system is what's in the repo. Changes show up as you make them, and you can easily pull up your repo's history.